# Simple TimeZone Question for Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, timezone

I'm new to things, but I'm using a "cookbook" program which will put its data to a Google Sheet.
All works OK, but I have two statements which are a problem:

```
var datenow = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EDT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm a'Z'").slice(0,10);
```

and

```
var timenow = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "America/NewYork", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm a'Z'").slice(11,19);
```

The example program used "PST" for the Pacific Standard Time Zone.
When I use this, I get a result which seems to be GMT.
I'd like to use EDT (Eastern Daylight Savings Time) and have tried various varieties (as above) with odd results.
Where am I going astray?  It seems simple, but I'm obviously doing something wrong!

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

- You should use `"America/New_York"` for US Eastern Time.  It will automatically choose EST or EDT depending on what is applicable.  Do not use time zone abbreviations.

  - For Pacific time, you should use `"America/Los_Angeles"`.  Again, don't use PST or PDT.
  - Refer to the [list of TZ Database Time Zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) for other options.
- The letters `T` and `Z` in a timestamp string have specific meaning:

  - `T` is the *time separator* in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.  Since you are using a 12-hour clock with am/pm indicator, you do not have an ISO 8601 timestamp, and should thus not use the letter `T` in your output.  Use a space instead, or switch to a 24-hour clock (`HH:mm` vs `hh:mm a`) if you want the string to be ISO 8601 compliant.
  - `Z` is the UTC indicator in the ISO 8601 format.  Since you are asking for the time in a specific time zone, you are not using UTC, and thus should not use the letter `Z` in your output string.  You can, however, include a time zone name or offset using `z`, `Z`, or `X` tokens - without placing it in quotes.
    In other words, you might use `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a z"`.
- Don't `slice` your output string.  Instead just provide the format tokens the way you would like the output to appear.  If you want separate `datenow` and `timenow` strings, then in one use `"yyyy-MM-dd"` and in the other use `"hh:mm a"`.

Comment: Thanks VERY much for your reply!    I can't absorb all of it in an instant,  but you seem to understand my problem, and your suggestions seem meaningful and helpful.  I'll work on implementing these ideas.